# Update from another table without double counting

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables, T1 and T2 (Sql Server 2008).

In T2 I don't have the Name info. What is the best way to fill it in T2?

If I do a join on the two tables, I would get a double count in T2 for Joe, because the same ID (06) appears twice in T1.
So it's probably best to do an update, but what's the right syntax?
Thank you for your advice.

```
T1
Name / ID / car / Country
Joe / 06 / BMW / Italy
Joe / 06 / WW / Italy
Tim / 07 / Jag / Spain


T2
Name / ID / Country
NULL / 06 / NULL
NULL / 07 / NULL
```

The result should be:

```
T2
Name / ID / Country
Joe / 06 / Italy
Tim / 07 / Spain
```

Comment: The best would almost always be to not store two copies of the same data. Assuming you know what you're doing, the UPDATE FROM query already posted as an answer should do your bidding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server's proprietary `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax can be used for this.

```
UPDATE T2
SET T2.Name = T1.Name, 
    T2.Country = T1.Country
FROM T2 JOIN T1 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

If multiple rows exist in `T1` for a particular `ID` an arbitrary one will be picked (this constrasts with `MERGE` which would abort the transaction with an error on finding this)

Edit: I'm not entirely certain that it is documented anywhere that with the above both columns are updated from the same row in the source. In practice I'm sure this will be the case but a way that doesn't rely on this (the execution plan uses the undocumented [`ANY` aggregate](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/07/02/undocumented-query-plans-the-any-aggregate.aspx)) would be.

```
;WITH T AS 
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Country, Name) AS RN
FROM T1       
)
UPDATE T2
SET T2.Name = T.Name, 
    T2.Country = T.Country
FROM T2 JOIN T ON T.ID = T2.ID   
WHERE T.RN = 1
```